# What is the criteria used to sort the users in the "participation" page shown in the meta sites?

Tags: support, meta, users

In any meta site for a Stack Exchange 2.0 site, there is a tab in the "users" page that shows the users basing on their participation. On the meta site for *Drupal Answers*, [that page](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation) appears as in the following screenshot (I limited the screenshot to the first two lines).

[image: screenshot]

To make a comparison, the [voters](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=voters) tab reports the number of votes casted from users.

[image: screenshot]

What are the criteria used to short the users in that page?

I recall the page showed more information for each user, which is not shown right now (I think it was the score the users got for their posts).

Comment: Sounds like it might just be the sum of all edits, comments and answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Current answer, see comment below:

> This is obsolete. Users > Participation is no longer limited to the last 60 days. Now includes views by Week, Month, Quarter, Year and ALL. –

---

Old answer:

All that's publicly known is:

> Users most active on this site in the last 60 days (combined number of posts, votes, comments and edits).

[image]

So, if you take that literally, that's your formula. But it could be that there are some multiplicators involved — I guess an answer counts more than just a comment.

Comment: This is obsolete. Users > Participation is no longer limited to the last 60 days. Now includes views by Week, Month, Quarter, Year and ALL.